# Преобразовать из массива объектов другой массив с объектами

Tags: javascript, react-native

Застопорился на таком моменте, знающих прошу помочь(

Мне нужно из такого массива:

```
const items = [
  { label: 'YouTube', value: 'YouTube' },
  { label: 'YouTube', value: 'YouTube' },
  { label: 'YouTube', value: 'YouTube' },
  { label: 'Вконтакте', value: 'Вконтакте' },
  { label: 'Вконтакте', value: 'Вконтакте' },
]
```

Получить такой массив:

```
const items = [
  { label: 'YouTube', value: 'YouTube' },
  { label: 'Вконтакте', value: 'Вконтакте' }
]
```

Как только не пытался, не выходит(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если порядок ключей гарантированно одинаков, можно ещё так:

```js
const items = [
  { label: 'YouTube', value: 'YouTube' },
  { label: 'YouTube', value: 'YouTube' },
  { label: 'YouTube', value: 'YouTube' },
  { value: 'Вконтакте', label: 'Вконтакте' },
  { value: 'Вконтакте', label: 'Вконтакте' },
];

const dedupedItems1 = [...new Set(items.map(obj => JSON.stringify(obj)))]
  .map(str => JSON.parse(str));

console.log(dedupedItems1);
```

Comment: Благодарю, очень помогли)

Answer (score 1):

Может так попробовать

```
const items = [


{ label: 'YouTube', value: 'YouTube' },
  { label: 'YouTube', value: 'YouTube' },
  { label: 'YouTube', value: 'YouTube' },
  { label: 'Вконтакте', value: 'Вконтакте' },
  { label: 'Вконтакте', value: 'Вконтакте' },
];

let result = items.reduce((acc,item) => { 
  let isExist = acc.filter(item2=>(item2.label==item.label) && (item2.value==item.value));
  if (!isExist) acc.push(item);
  return acc;}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: К сожалению, Ваш вариант не сработал для меня(
Спасибо Вам большое за отклик

Comment: Возможно, в объектах есть и другие ключи, которые нужно сравнивать.